# Website not displaying correctly on mobile

Tags: html, css

To start off I am not an expert at this, as a matter of fact I'm following along in a online course.  My test website comes out fine on desktop but on mobile it's misaligned and squished. I have already used this:

```html
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes"
```

and other variants of this but nothing seems to work.  Here is a link to the github page:

https://wunray.github.io/cv/

Can anyone explain to a novice what exactly is going on to cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there's nothing wrong with your meta tags. It's just a css problem.
With these changes, your site perfectly fits on mobile:

- You have some elements with negative right positioning. Either make them `right: 0` on mobile, or add `overflow-x: hidden` to a parent element (ie. body).
- Add `img { max-width: 100% }` to your css so images don't exceed window size.

Comment: This seems to work, but another question or problem.  It all fits on the page but when I use my fingers to zoom out it then breaks the page (or should I say allows me to zoom all the way out) is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Glad it worked ! I think that 'topcloud' is also overflowing from the page. It's currently `left: 500px`, but you could do something like `left: 30%`.

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed it! Spent like maybe 2 hours trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

The page design is breaking because of your css. Meta tag is fine.

In h1 tag you can use ->

```
word-break: break-word;
```

Also adjusting width of img will make the page responsive.

[image]